# Moving Files from Azure blob storage to Google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-functions, azure-functions, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi guys i will be happy to get your help. i got a task to moving files from azure storage to google cloud storage bucket, The file transfer need to be done by a trigger, whenever a new file is uploaded to azure storage, a function that listens to blob trigger, transfers it to GCP bucket, I did a demo and was able to get the function to move the files between different storage accounts in azure, but the function is unable to transfer the files to Google cloud storage bucket, I do not rule out a way to do the file transfer from google storage to azure storage if anyone has a good way to do it on the part of GCP. I am adding here the code with which my function ran from the azure (wrote in powershell) .
Does anyone have a good way of doing this or has he done it before and can help?

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write out the blob name and size to the information log.
Write-Host "PowerShell Blob trigger function Processed blob! Name: $($TriggerMetadata.Name) Size: $($InputBlob.Length) bytes"

# Define source, source contains the blob newly uploaded(with file name)
$SourceURI = "https://ContainerTEST.blob.core.windows.net/"
$SourceBlobContainer = "testcontainer/"
$SourceSASToken = "d,xmsetgijazjss23139sclzxx@#@!skskkxazzzz"
$SourceFullPath = "$($SourceURI)$($SourceBlobContainer)$($TriggerMetadata.Name)$($SourceSASToken)"



# del azcopy.exe and download lastest version of azcopy
# del azcopy.exe

# Test if AzCopy.exe exists in current folder
$AzcoypFile = "azcopy.exe"
$AzCopyExists = Test-Path $AzcoypFile
Write-Host "AzCopy exists:" $AzCopyExists

# Download AzCopy.zip and unzip if it doesn't exist
If ($AzCopyExists -eq $False)
{
    Write-Host "AzCopy not found. Downloading..."
    
    #Download AzCopy
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows" -OutFile AzCopy.zip -UseBasicParsing
 
    #unzip azcopy
    write-host "unzip azcopy.zip"
    Expand-Archive ./AzCopy.zip ./AzCopy -Force

    # Copy AzCopy to current dir
    Get-ChildItem ./AzCopy/*/azcopy.exe | Copy-Item -Destination "./AzCopy.exe"
}

$googlecloudpath = "https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/GoogleBucketTEST"


Write-Host "copy blob from  $($SourceFullPath) to  $($googlecloudpath)"
./azcopy.exe copy $SourceFullPath $googlecloudpath --recursive=true
```

Comment: AzCopy will not help you to do this as it only support Azure AD & SAS for [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#authorize-azcopy)

Comment: Is there another method I can copy the files by trigger to GCP?

Comment: You must read the Azure container blob using Azure APIs and write the object to Google Cloud Storage using Google APIs and use the correct authorization for each cloud. PowerShell support in Google Cloud is very limited. You will need to switch languages to C#/.NET, or Python, etc unless you can write low-level PowerShell directly to REST APIs.

Comment: Hi i am working right now to make a function from azure that base on blob trigger to copy the files to Google cloud storage in Python , I'm kind of struggling can you give me an example code that i can use it ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries  and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#client-libraries and https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Found an article which can help you to move or copies the azure blob files to Google cloud storage bucket
Use GCP Data Transfer Service that will import data from Azure Blob to GCP storge bucket.

Step 1: Use the Transfer Service Cloud option and fill the storage account, container name and SAS Access token of azure storage.

Step 2: Select Google Storage Bucket where you want data to be copied over from Azure Storage.

Step 3: Select the schedule of how often data need to be copied over to GCP Storage from Azure Storage and click create will create the job.

Step 4: Monitor schedule job.

Reference: https://amald-nav.medium.com/use-gcp-data-transfer-service-import-data-from-azure-blob-f2469f42a5c2

Comment: Hi i have tried this solution but the schedule job can be run only one hour at minimum and i need the copy files to be done more frequently like every minute ( or trigger ) .